# Yii2 dropdownlist selected index on update

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii2, selected

I have tried using the examples provided on default value for a dropdownlist in Yii2 but the explanations are not clear enough for me to understand and the nothing is working for me. I have 2 tables, one called jobs and the other called customers. The dropdown list in the create function in jobs controller works fine. Here is the code:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Jobs();            
    $this->view->params['customer_list'] = ArrayHelper::map(Customers::find() 
     ->orderBy(['(last_name)' => SORT_ASC])
     ->all(),'id','fullName');      
    // ...
}
```

In the form view:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'customer_id')->dropDownList($this->params['customer_list'],['prompt'=>'-Choose a Customer-']) ?>
```

What I want is on update to show the entire list from the customer table with the selected customer in the jobs table in the dropdown to be the selected value in the dropdownlist so that the user can select a different customer than the one currently selected.

Please provide a complete answer with both controller and form code. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Providing the full controller and form code is excessive since it has been given in multiple places already. Many examples are available in the Guide ([[1]](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-controllers.html), [[2]](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-forms.html)) and you can always take a look how it's done in the Project Templates ([[3]](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/frontend/controllers/SiteController.php), [[4]](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/frontend/views/site/signup.php)).

First of all, there is no need to pass the variables using `$this->view->params` since you can pass them directly from controller to view like:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $customer_list = ArrayHelper::map(Customers::find() 
        ->orderBy(['last_name' => SORT_ASC])
        ->all(), 'id', 'fullName');

    return $this->render('create', [
        // ...
        'customer_list' => $customer_list
    ]);
}
```

Now in the view `create` there is `$customer_list` variable available. Using `$this->view->params` works as well but is is made rather to pass variables between views.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'customer_id')->dropDownList($customer_list, ['prompt' => '-Choose a Customer-']) ?>
```

As for the dropdown:

ActiveField `dropDownList()` method is designed to show selected value when one of the given option items matches the value of `$model`'s attribute (in this case it's `'customer_id'`) so all you need to do to is to set this attribute.

If `Jobs` is an instance of ActiveRecord action can look something like that:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = Jobs::findOne($id); // $id is primary key in the DB table for Jobs model

    // operations on $model here

    $customer_list = ArrayHelper::map(Customers::find() 
        ->orderBy(['last_name' => SORT_ASC])
        ->all(), 'id', 'fullName');

    return $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model,
        'customer_list' => $customer_list
    ]);
}
```

Now the same code for `dropDownList()` in the view shows `'customer_id'` selected with the value saved with `$model`.

If `Jobs` is an instance of the form Model you can pass the `'customer_id'` of your choice as well:

```
public function actionUpdate()
{
    $model = new Jobs();
    $model->customer_id = 1; // example

    // operations on $model here

    $customer_list = ArrayHelper::map(Customers::find() 
        ->orderBy(['last_name' => SORT_ASC])
        ->all(), 'id', 'fullName');

    return $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model,
        'customer_list' => $customer_list
    ]);
}
```

Now the same code for `dropDownList()` in the view shows `'customer_id'` selected with the value of 1 (if there is an item of that value).

Comment: First, I was unable to pass the variable from the controller to the view using the method you offered as an alternative. That is not a big deal since it works using $this->view->params['customer_list'] method. The example you gave to show the selected item is $model->customer_id = 1. However, what I want is the customer_id from the current record in the job table to be the one that is selected. Can you just show me how to do that? Thanks.

Comment: Disregard the above comment. I figured this out. The form on update automatically shows the value from the table as the selected item. There is nothing that needs to be done.